# Terminal changed and does not open jupyter notebook

Tags: macos, jupyter-notebook, zsh

I'm using macOS Big Sur and till last week, i was only seeing `berkay.alan@` when i enter to a terminal. `berkay.alan@` is my username in my computer. But after i pushed something to Github, it changed and became `berkay.alan@BerkayAlann` as below.i have no username as "BerkayAlann" anywhere and i dunno what that is. Normally i could enter to jupyter notebook when i write "jupyter notebook" but it gives me an error as below.

This is how my terminal looks like:

[image: This is how my terminal look like]

Do you have any idea what and why this could be?

Comment: This isn't really related to Git. It's just a zsh thing: the zsh prompt just shows you extra stuff at times. The `command not found: jupyter` part is the actual problem and it just means that wherever you installed jupyter, that's not in your zsh `$PATH` setting any more. Why *that* is, is the next question.

Comment: Looks like you have messed up your zsh startup files. As a first step, I would do a `zsh -l -x` and analyze the output, first of all on where you modify the PATH. After you have fixed this, you can go on and repair your prompt.

Comment: i have tried but i could not find the way to repair.